# Converting single-band Grayscale GeoTIFF to RGB using GDAL

Tags: gdal

I have a need to convert a single-band (Uint16) Grayscale GeoTIFF to 3-band RGB grayscale GeoTIFF. When I use the command:

```
gdal_translate <source grayscale file> -expand rgb -ot UInt16 <output RGB file>
```

I get the following error message: `ERROR 1: Error : band 1 has no color table`

Is there a correct way of doing this in GDAL?

Comment: I can't understand what is `3-band RGB grayscale GeoTIFF`, could you explain?

Comment: I need to load GeoTIFF data into a platform for analysis. Unfortunately, the platform only supports GeoTIFFs that are 3 band (RGB) + Alpha band. So I'd like to essentially create a 4 band grayscale GeoTIFFs from a 1 band grayscale GeoTIFFs.

Comment: Ok, term grayscale means usually a single band image so perhaps I would call the result as RGB image with only gray shades.

Answer (score 3):

Select the one and only band three times for the output

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -b 1 -b 1 -b 1 -ot UInt16 gray.tif 3band.tif
```

Comment: Just curious if you know how to convert it to an rgba image with 255 for the alpha?